# How to determine model of smartphone connected to my device

Tags: android, bluetooth

I want to know is there any way to determine model of smartphone connected to my android device via bluetooth programmatically? I know how to make bluetooth connection between two android devices, but how to request information of smartphone's model? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [BluetoothManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothManager.html) for this task:

```
List<BluetoothDevice> connectedDevices = this.getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE)
                                            .getConnectedDevices(BluetoothProfile.GATT); //or BluetoothProfile.GATT_SERVER

for(BluetoothDevice bd : connectedDevices){
    String remoteName = bd.getName();
//do something
}
```